# Is it possible to detect code in String using Regex?

Tags: regex

For example :

For the following Text:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eum ut vitae quidam mentitum, eu eum malorum eligendi tincidunt. Vix te vitae tamquam, mea nisl praesent ea, vis omnis postulant in

import sys def fun(){print('Hello')} fun()

Mea veri fierent explicari eu, ne appareat convenire mei. Dicat neglegentur definitiones nec id, sit facete cotidieque in. Intellegam referrentur cu cum, an mandamus periculis pro.
```

How can we use regex (or some other technique) to find if there is code in there or not). Code can be in java/python/C/css/js etc.

(Also I observed while posting the question that if the code is not formatted properly, stack overflow raises a warning, any idea how is it getting done?)

Comment: `if there is code in there or not` how would you identify that?

Comment: What if the code is written in [Shakespeare](http://shakespearelang.sourceforge.net/report/shakespeare/)?

Comment: My first instinct would be to use Artificial Intelligence and/or statistical analysis. You'd presumably need to target specific languages either way. Trying to do it in regex will involve a whole lot of manual analysis and hard coding, and would likely end up being pretty prone to mistakes even if you do it well. But that seems like something you can write a paper or 10 on, so it's seems way too broad for the question/answer format of Stack Overflow. You can ask on [meta] how Stack Overflow does it (and only that), but I'm guessing that's been answered already at some point.

Comment: Detecting code anywhere inside prose, without an indicator where it is supposed to start is inherently hard. At least it is for languages like C, in which keywords are a rare occurence. Compilers have a similar job, but not the same. They scan text which is supposed to be code and just need to complain if it isn't. The result is the infamous "syntax error", which is more BASIC than C, but you get the idea. If you are to tolerate non-code and then pick up text which could be considered code, you probably would end up more or less compiling and when it fails delete the first "word" and retry.

Comment: @jwodder. No shakespeare!! or Chef or lolcode!! Just trying to target some specific languages.

Comment: @Yunnosch. I liked that idea to remove a word and try to compile it using different compilers. Will definitely look into it. Thanks a lot. May be including a print statement after the first word, then second and third etc upto some n words (depending on how much time it will take), and if no prints executed, then remove the word  Does that sound okay?

Comment: Unsure what you mean by "including a print statement after the first word". You probably want to keep all text. For that I propose to (after the first compilation failure) insert a start of comment (e.g. `/*`for C) at the very beginning and then move the end of comment (`*/`) from word boundary to word boundary. That would keep all the input text. However, the whole concept will fail if the compileable part does not go all the way to the end of the text. It would probably require a second comment, starting after compileable part. I.e. a two dimensional search, assuming 1 code part, not more.

Comment: Here is a concept based on assumptions. E.g. you make the assumption, that code looks like `word word(word word){ NoCurlyBraces; }`. Then you make a regular expression to find that. This is not hard. But that assumption is easily broken by lots of perfectly correct code parts. So you make more assumptions, covered by regexes.  This works the better the fewer assumptions are needed to describe all pieces of code you want to detect. It works less well, the more creative the coders are. I tried that recently for an actual project. It was surprisingly hard, in spite of coding style rules.